# What is the charging energy in relation to a superconducting transmon?

Tags: experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

The transmon achieves its reduced sensitivity to charge noise by significantly increasing the ratio of the Josephson energy to the charging energy. What is this charging energy?